# Submitting dynamic edit form with Jquery in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an Android applciation with phonegap, jQuery (1.9.1) and jQuery Mobile (1.3.1). Using Ripple extension.

I'm facing problem in submitting edit record form.

Here is the scenario;
When the application starts the first time, and I go for edit record form the new values are submitted correctly, name John is changed to Phil. However, if return to the edit form again, and update the form the record doesn't get updated, name Phil is not changed to Michael.

Console shows the same old value in the javascript variable. Name Phil rather than Micheal.
Here is my code.

```
function editFormWithRecord(tx, result) {
    keeperRecord = result.rows.item(0);
    $page = $('<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="editKeeperForm">
               <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">Edit Form</div>
               <div data-role="content">
               <form method="POST" action="editKeeperForm" id="editKeeper"
    onsubmit="editForm(' + keeperRecord.fld_id + ')" data-ajax="false" >
                 <input type="text" name="name2" id="name" placeholder="Name" 
    value="' + keeperRecord.fld_keeperName + '">
                 <input type="submit" id="save"  value="Save">
               </form>
                 </div> <!-- content -->');
    $page.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    $page.page();
    $.mobile.changePage($page);
}

function editForm(id) {
    //This shows me nothing in console, just a blank line.
    console.log($("#name").val());
    //So I use
    console.log($("#editKeeper").find("#name").val());
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1) you're missing `</div>` to close page div. 2) duplicate IDs is causing this problem. 3) you dont need this `$page.page();`.

Comment: @Omar, each field has different ID. I corrected the other corrections you mentioned, thanks!
One more thing, since I'm handling the form, and data-ajax is false shouldn't I leave the action empty? jQuery docs was a bit confusing for me.

Comment: I guess action should contain URL, not sure though. You're welcome bro :)

Comment: @omar, any other idea why `console.log($("#editKeeper").find("#name").val());` retaining the old vlaue?

Comment: Because of duplicate IDs. When you inject a new page, you should change id of fields. Another way, use this `console.log( $.mobile.activePage.find("#editKeeper").val() )`.